# Zabbix Proxy Server Error Message: The Proxy does not match Zabbix Database

Tags: database, proxy, zabbix

I installed a Zabbix Proxy but it won´t start. In the Proxy log is following printed:

The Proxy does not match Zabbix Database. Current database version (mandatory/optional): 03020000/03020000. Required mandatory version: 02040000

Comment: You seem to be running a Zabbix 2.4 proxy on a Zabbix 3.2 database.

Comment: i used the zabbix-3.2.1.tar.gz folder from zabbix.com for the installation ...

Comment: nobody knows a solution?